# jquery .load() not working onclick

Tags: jquery, load

I'm trying to have a site set up so when the page loads there is a div that dynamically pulls it's content from a .html page I have set up.  I have a bunch of thumbnails at the top and when you click one I want the content from a different .html document to replace what every was in that div that was dynamically loaded into the first time.

To do this I'm trying to use the jquery .load() feature.  What I tried to do was set up a function:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function space_load() {

$('#SPACE_TOTAL').load('http://www.klossal.com/portfolio/space.html');
}
</script>
```

and then tried to launch it using:

```
onclick="space_load();"
```

this didn't work and I was wondering if anyone could help me with this.  The other thing I was wondering is if this were to work, would it replace the content that was previously loaded into there?  I might be getting a head of myself and it just does this on it's own.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, your code has invalid structure

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    function space_load() {
        $('#SPACE_TOTAL').load('http://www.klossal.com/portfolio/space.html');
    }    
    space_load(); //Now call the function
});
```

However, you can trim it down do this

```
$(function() {
    $('#SPACE_TOTAL').load('http://www.klossal.com/portfolio/space.html');
});
```

But, since you want this on click of an element. **This is what you need:**

```
$(function() {
    $("#yourlinkid").click(function() {
        $('#SPACE_TOTAL')
           .html('<img src="preloader.gif" />')
           .load('http://www.klossal.com/portfolio/space.html');
    });
});
```

Comment: it was mentioned early and I hadn't thought of this, but is there a way to give it a load .gif that goes away when it's finished loading?

Comment: and it just goes away when it finishes loading?

Comment: @loriensleafs, Yup, it is really that easy :)

Comment: last question, do I still launch this with onclick?

Comment: @loriensleafs, No it will attach itself to the element with `id="yourlinkid"`, so just change part

Answer (score 4):

Do you need to document.ready here? I think you could simply invoke the function when the click happens.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
 function space_load() {
  $('#SPACE_TOTAL').load('http://www.klossal.com/portfolio/space.html');
 }
</script>
```

and then...

```
onclick="space_load();"
```

Making the assumption that `#SPACE_TOTAL` is not a container that is dynamically populated at runtime, at which point you would need to wrap a `document.ready`.

Comment: Is the DOM guaranteed to be completely ready when the link is displayed?

Comment: Yes I agree, but going on what has been posted it's not stipulated that this is the case.

Comment: I had thought using this that #SPACE_TOTAL was the div that the url was loading into?  I hadn't thought about the loading part actually, good point.

Answer (score 2):

At first you don't need the `$(document).ready()` and second is you forgot to close the `ready()` method. `);` is missing at the end of your JS.