# can't get event listener working

Tags: jquery, event-listener, webkit-transition

I have an event listener that I'm trying to get working and can't seem to get it to run.  I have a onclick set up that switches the classes of a div prompting a webkit transition.  When that transition ends I want jquery to load an external page into the div but it doesn't ever load it.  This is the js I have set up

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function fullscreen_slider_load() {
var fullscreen = document.getElementById("fullscreen");

function fullscreen_done1() {
    console.log("done called");
    fullscreen.removeEventListener("webkitTransitionEnd", fullscreen_done1);
    fullscreen.addEventListener("webkitTransitionEnd", fullscreen_done2);
    $(function fullscreen_load() {
    $('#fullscreen')
       .html('<img src="http://www.klossal.com/loader.gif"/>')
       .load('http://www.klossal.com/portfolio/space_fullscreen.html');
});


function fullscreen_done2() {
    fullscreen.removeEventListener("webkitTransitionEnd", fullscreen_done2);

};
</script>
```

I'm not sure why it's not loading, but any help I can get on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: hmm.. something doesn't look right.  Where are the closing braces for the first two functions?  Are you looking to nest functions or something?

Answer (score 0):

This part of your code makes no sense to me and does not look consistent with what you said you wanted to happen.  Also the code you posted doesn't appear to have proper bracing:

```
$(function fullscreen_load() {
$('#fullscreen')
   .html('<img src="http://www.klossal.com/loader.gif"/>')
   .load('http://www.klossal.com/portfolio/space_fullscreen.html');
});
```

If I understand this right, it will set up a `document.ready()` event handler for loading new content into `#fullscreen`.  I do not think that's what you want here.

I also don't see anywhere where you are adding the event listener that triggers `fullscreen_done1()` and I don't see any reason for the `fullscreen_done2()` event listener as it isn't used here.

If you just want the fullscreen object to load some new content when the first CSS transition is done and you have registered the event listener that will call `fullscreen_done1()` somewhere else, you can use this (fixed indentation and bracing):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function fullscreen_slider_load() {
    var fullscreen = document.getElementById("fullscreen");

    function fullscreen_done1() {
        console.log("done called");
        fullscreen.removeEventListener("webkitTransitionEnd", fullscreen_done1);
        fullscreen.addEventListener("webkitTransitionEnd", fullscreen_done2);
        $(fullscreen)
           .html('<img src="http://www.klossal.com/loader.gif"/>')
           .load('http://www.klossal.com/portfolio/space_fullscreen.html');
    }

    function fullscreen_done2() {
        fullscreen.removeEventListener("webkitTransitionEnd", fullscreen_done2);
    }
}
</script>
```

If you were trying to do something more involved than this provides, then please clarify what else you were trying to do after the first transition finishes.

P.S. When you don't indent the code under function declarations, it makes it very easy to misunderstand the intent of your code.

Your code also won't work in Firefox or Opera (non-webkit browsers that support CSS3 transitions).

Comment: So that first part I actually use in another part of my site and it does function, here is one of them <script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("#glow_launch").click(function() {
        $('#MAIN_CONTAINER')
           .html('<img src="http://www.klossal.com/loader.gif" style="padding-bottom:1000px;"/>') 
           .load('http://www.klossal.com/portfolio/light2_overview.html');
    });
});
</script>

Comment: I'm new at this so I'm still very much trying to figure things out.  What I was trying to do was when the transition finishes it prompts that url http://www.klossal.com/portfolio/space_fullscreen.html to be loaded into the div "fullscreen".  Does that make sense?

Comment: @loriensleafs - Did you try to code I recommended?  I added a few more comments to my answer about that first block of code.  I now maybe understand where you got it, but it's not doing the right thing for you here.

Comment: @loriensleafs - When you say "prompts that url ... to be loaded", I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: it takes that url's content and loads it into the div fullscreen.  http://www.klossal.com/portfolio/index_current_alt2.html  this is set up on this page where I use it.  If you click any of the large thumbs at teh top it takes teh content of the div "maincontainer" and replaces it with the content of the page the url directs it to.

Comment: http://www.klossal.com/portfolio/index_current_alt2.html if you scroll down to where it says "a litle bit of info" right above that there are two thumb nails and a link that says fullscreen album, if you click that it actually loads the content from the url http://www.klossal.com/portfolio/space_fullscreen.html into the fullscreen layer, it does it with an onclick though, I'm just trying to figure out how to change this to a event listener.  I did try teh updated code and unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: @loriensleafs - Unfortunately, I'm unable to understand what you're asking for as you've only shown us a piece of the relevant code and none of the relevant HTML/CSS.  For example, I don't even know if your `fullscreen_load()` function is getting called.  If it does, the code in my answer should do what I thought you were originally asking for.  If it doesn't, then I don't know if it's not getting called or I didn't understand what you wanted.  The ball is in your court to explain your question better.

Comment: hmmm okay, let me start over, sorry to be unclear.  I have a page where there is a button to view a gallery.  I'm trying to load the gallery into an overlay that slides down from the top of the screen.  The overlay is a div with an id of "fullscreen".  I am prompting it to animate by swapping classes set up like this: http://jsfiddle.net/9NJP9/10/  I'm trying to load content of the url of the gallery into the "fullscreen" div.  I have the gallery here at this URL http://www.klossal.com/portfolio/space_fullscreen.html you can view it there in that page.

Comment: I was hoping to load this content from the url  klossal.com/portfolio/space_fullscreen.html into fullscreen div when the webkit transition of the fullscreen div is complete, I was trying to do this with an event listener.

Comment: to be more specific about the loading, like  I said I'd like to load the content from that url into the div, I used teh second answer to the post here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9872087/jquery-load-not-working-onclick

Comment: @loriensleafs - Is the entire extent of your question "How to hook up an event listener for a click event"?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13960/discussion-between-loriensleafs-and-jfriend00)